# Defining a new function to be holomorphic by construction

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions, analytic-functions

Given that some $f(z)$ is analytic on the unit disc, $f(0) = 0$, and $|f(z)| \leq M$, I want to show that $|f(z)| \leq M|z|$ on the unit disc.

I want to use the Maximum Modulus Principle (MMP) on a new function, $h(z)$, which will be defined as $\frac{f(z)}{z}$ everywhere but $0$, and be defined at $0$ such that $h(z)$ is holomorphic.  Given that $f(0) = 0$, I was thinking of defining $h(0) = 0$, but am not sure how to then prove that $h(z)$ is holomorphic at $0$.

I tried the limit approach, but wasn't really sure how to proceed beyond just writing it down.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Essentially duplicate ofhttps://math.stackexchange.com/questions/138850/proof-of-the-schwarz-lemma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: The derivative is defined by
$$f'(z)=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h}$$

Alternatively you could argue with the power series of $f$.

Comment: Would the power series approach consist of writing $$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_nz^n $$ and then, from the definition of $h(z)$, writing $$h(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{z} c_n z^n $$ and then noting that the radius of convergence of the newly defined power series is unchanged from the radius of convergence of $f(z)$ expressed as a power series?

Comment: I'm also not sure I understand the significant of the hint involving the derivative definition. Actually, I didn't even know there was another definition for $f'(z)$ other than $$ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(z + h) - f(z)}{h} $$

Comment: No, there is no different definition. I just want to show you how to define the function $h$ at zero using the limit approach.

Comment: The other approach would give you $h(0)=c_1$. Now think about how you can calculate $c_1$ using the function $f$